# Calling WCF Service in Multithreading Environment that has 2 different .SVC Files. Error while calling both service at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, wcf, visual-studio-2015

I have an application which has two .SVC files specific for two different modules. 
In the existing Application, we are making calls one after the other within the same thread. I never had issue.

As part of the Refactoring, i cleaned them calling them those services from two different threads (First thread calls first method and second thread calls second method). These two methods are even different. Sometimes code is executing without any issues. but Sometimes, I am getting below error saying that could not find Instance. Again this error doesn't always happen.

```
      Exception:
                RMS Conversion failed : System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: ComponentActivator: 

could not instantiate Axis.Edc.Service.RMS.RMSConversionService (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
    Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException: ComponentActivator: could not instantiate RMS.RMSConversionService ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ----> System.InvalidOperationException: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator...).
```

Here is the code call to the service:

```
public EnumConversionStatus GenerateRmsImportFiles(int submissionId)
        {
            lock (new object())
            {
                using (var client = new RMSConversionService.RMSConversionServiceClient())
                {
                    var result = client.GenerateRmsImportFiles(submissionId);
                    client.Close();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }


public EnumConversionStatus GenerateAirImportFiles(int submissionId)
        {
            lock (new object())
            {
                using (var client = new AIRConversionService.AirConversionServiceClient())
                {
                    var result = client.GenerateAirImportFiles(submissionId);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here we have two different endpoints for 2 different SVC Services. 
Also here we have lock. I am not sure how to exactly get around this error?

Thanks,
Rita

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `WCF` you have 2 or more thread trying that call your `GenerateRmsImportFiles()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lock (new object())` creates a new object every time. This means each thread lock on different objects. This is not locking at all.

If your two services do not use the same resource, there is no lock needed. 
But as I can see from your exception, you are using shared resource between both services - which is Entity framework DbContext.

I suppose that one thread is initializing DbContext and at the same time the second thread is using the same DbContext. As you can see from exception message:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

A better locking would be:

```
private object _lock = new object();

    public EnumConversionStatus GenerateRmsImportFiles(int submissionId)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    using (var client = new RMSConversionService.RMSConversionServiceClient())
                    {
                        var result = client.GenerateRmsImportFiles(submissionId);
                        client.Close();
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }


    public EnumConversionStatus GenerateAirImportFiles(int submissionId)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    using (var client = new AIRConversionService.AirConversionServiceClient())
                    {
                        var result = client.GenerateAirImportFiles(submissionId);
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I will try this. But the point is, they are two different Services although they are in the same project. Wondering howcome they are interferring and also one method is called from one Thread and second method is called from second thread. .

Comment: I would use a different lock object for both otherwise once one is accessed the other one will be locked.

Comment: Yaa. This may work. But as i said, First method is called from first  Thread and second method is called from second thread. No clue howcome they are interferring.

Comment: @Rita Did you try my solution at all? I have updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Karel, I tried this. Worked well. Thank you. Also i am testing to see by switching the WCF service mode from Singleton to PerCall if that allows New Instance.